# Input from a text file to get a char C++

Tags: c++, file, text, input

I am having trouble with getting input after a modifier in the text of a .txt file.
What I want to do is if the .txt file has the word "type:" then anything after that will be put into a char.
My code so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "VKH.h"
#include "Strmif.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

void GetDocumentandRead() {
string line;
ifstream myfile (line1);
if (myfile.is_open())
{
  while ( !myfile.eof() )
  {
    getline (myfile,line);
    char aline[100];
    strcpy(aline, line.c_str());
    printf(aline, "\n");
    if (line.compare("mouseup") == 0){
        MouseUp(10);
    }
    if (line.compare("mousedown") == 0){
        MouseDown(10);
    }
    if (line.compare("mouseright") == 0){
        MouseRight(10);
    }
    if (line.compare("mouseleft") == 0){
        MouseLeft(10);
    }
    if (line.compare("mouseclick") == 0){
        MouseClick();
    }
    if (line.compare("enter") == 0){
        Enter();
    }
    if (line.compare("ctrltab") == 0){
        CtrlTab();
    }
    if (line.compare("tab") == 0){
        Tab();
    }
    if (line.compare("altf4") == 0){
        AltF4(0);
    }
    if (line.compare("alttab") == 0){
        AltTab();
    }
    if (line.compare("mousecenter") == 0){
        MouseCenter();
    }
    if (line.compare(6,5,"type:") == 0){
      //Don't know what to put here...
    }
  }
  myfile.close();
 }

 else printf("\nUnable to open file\n\n");

}
```

So after the "type:" in a text file it would type that using a function I have called TypeStr();

```
void TypeStr(char *lpszString)
{
  char cChar;
  while((cChar=*lpszString++)) // loops through chars
  {
    short vk=VkKeyScan(cChar); // keycode of char
    if((vk>>8)&1){keybd_event(VK_LSHIFT,0,0,0);} // hold shift if necessary
    keybd_event((unsigned char)vk,0,0,0); // key in
    keybd_event((unsigned char)vk,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0); // key out
    if((vk>>8)&1){keybd_event(VK_LSHIFT,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);} // release shift if necessary
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Apart from posting a **small** sample of an existing "text" file that has input to go with this code, you've stated what you want. Is this the entirety of what you've tried to *get* that ? debugged it perhaps? What does it seem to be doing from your testing and debugging?

Answer (score 3):

First you should rewrite your `TypeStr` function so that it takes a `const char *`. Like this

```
void TypeStr(const char *lpszString)
{
    ...
}
```

no other changes needed.

Then you should call that function from your code like this

```
if (line.compare(6,5,"type:") == 0){
   TypeStr(line.c_str() + 11);
}
```

The reason that you have to change your `TypeStr` function to `const char*` (apart from it being general good style) is that the `c_str()` method of `std::string` returns a `const char*` not a `char*`.

Comment: Why +11, should it not be +6 for characters after "type:"?

Comment: @acraig5075 Because the comparison starts at the 6th character of line, "type:" is then the next five characters, so the first character after "type:" is the 11th character of line (all counting form zero of course).

Comment: Thanks! I already use a char *lpszString in the TypeStr method. very helpful!

Also this works for me:
    char aline[100];
    strcpy(aline, line.c_str());
    TypeStr(aline + 11);

I don't know why.

Comment: @user1815591 Well `aline` is a copy of `line` so `line.cstr() + 11` and `aline + 11` are the same thing. I was wondering about `aline`, I couldn't see any reason in your code to use it. It's generally a bad idea to have two copies of the same information in a program. And of course if your line happened to be more than 100 characters then using `aline` would fail. Unless you have a good reason to keep it I would remove it.